# Delphi PPL Task Priority

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ppl

I tried to google this, but was not able to find a example . I also tried searching the PPL library itself for Priority, but only found one commented out line about it :)

My "problem" is , I have 4 Threads , I run these on a 4 Core CPU . For a brief moment I peek out at 100% , the entire process takes no longer then 20 seconds .

Is there a way to set the Priority for the Threads ?

My reason is, I have MSSQL installed on this computer . And I am not 100% sure . If my Threads peek for 20 sec at 100% if the SQL Server is slower then or not.

Thank you.

Comment: the OS handles that for you, it is called [scheduling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/scheduling).

Comment: I was talking about Thread Priority , Low, Normal, High, Critical ....

Comment: you can alter the priority for the threads in Delphi, but I would advise against it, let the OS handle it...

Comment: Anyway the answer to your question would be "No" as with ITask, there is no way to alter the priority.

Comment: at-least I feel better :) I will do as you suggested. It self tunes and it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, as it seems it is self-tuning.

Just downloaded CPU-Z ... started the Stress Text . And my own Threads automatically slowed down . For my current situation works as expected.

Thank you.